# Cannot change input type using inline JavaScript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Why doesn't this work in Firefox but does in Chrome?

```
<input onfocus="(this.type='datetime-local')" onblur="(this.type='text')" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Firefox doesn’t support `<input type="datetime-local">` at all.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) Nothing to do with the JavaScript.